# Can I set a static ip address for WSL 2?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, wsl-2

I'm doing some Ruby on Rails development on a WSL 2. The rails app connects to a MySQL server running on my Windows host. When I used WSL 1 it as easy to set the host to 127.0.0.1 but on WSL 2 I have to use the nameserver written in `/etc/resolv.conf`

But I found out that IP address written in resolv.conf changes on reboots.

Is there a way to set a static IP address for WSL 2 ?

Comment: Note: if you are using Windows 11, there is a new option. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881373/6309)

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with running MySql in a docker that solved the problem as well

Comment: May 2023: there is a new-new option, using Windows registry keys. See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881373/6309).

Comment: Sept. 2023: native static IP support is on the horizon! See [my edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72881373/6309).

Answer (score 8):

Update Sept. 2023: [WSL issue 4210](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4210#issuecomment-1726501512) and [Craig Loewen](https://github.com/craigloewen-msft) (Program Manager at Microsoft) point to "[Windows Subsystem for Linux September 2023 update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2023-update/)"

> In your `.wslconfig` file you can set `experimental.networkingMode=mirrored`, as well as some other key settings that should improve your network compatibility!
> This feature should allow you to set a static IP as you will get the IP address of the Windows host. Please try them out and let us know what you think.
>
> Please note: You need to be on a Windows Insiders version to use the new networking settings (Any channel of Windows Insiders will do, including release preview). If you see the "These are not supported" messages it means that your current Windows version doesn't have support, and you will need to upgrade. These features will eventually be coming to Windows 11 22H2.

---

You can consider [**ocroz/wsl2-boot**](https://github.com/ocroz/wsl2-boot) ([see `INSTALL`](https://github.com/ocroz/wsl2-boot/blob/master/INSTALL.md) for installation instructions):

> After running `wsl-boot` command:
>
> - The WSL network is configured as per its predefined definition always (Windows side),
> - All WSL hosts are configured with their predefined static IP always (Linux side),
> - All WSL hosts and connected Hyper-V VMs can talk to each other always,
> - The DNS resolution works however you are connected to Internet or VPN,
> - You can SSH to WSL host without any delay.

---

Dec. 2022, [`microsoft/WSL` issue 4210](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4210#issuecomment-1359703811) also adds:

> With the latest Windows 11 (22621+), you can already specify the network adapter you want to use for WSL2 in `.wslconfig`:
>
> ```ini
> [wsl2]
> networkingMode=bridged
> vmSwitch=my-switch
> ipv6=true
> ```
>
> So, now you can create a Hyper-V external virtual switch for WSL2 and fix the IP address, no other scripts are required. It works out-of-box.

The [same thread adds](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4210#issuecomment-1371944639):

> 1. Create a vSwitch in Hyper-V，I Use Hyper-V Gui to do this.   Hyper-V has three types of virtual switches -- external, internal, and private.
>    I choose the "`external`" type , which is `bridge` type, the same as VMWare workstation.
> 2. set this config in .wslconfig
> 3. I find the IP change to the network of my home router，which is replace the old of eth0.
>    You can set DHCP in you home router, then Fix the IP of the bridge.
>
> To sum up, in the case of bridge, it is essentially DHCP , and whether it is fixed or not depends on the DHCP server.

And [in May 2023](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4210#issuecomment-1559641163), from [Azure Zeng](https://github.com/AzureZeng):

> I have found something interesting in the latest version of WSL2.
>
> The WSL Network IP range and gateway IP can be found, and be changed in the following registry key:
>
> - `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\NatGatewayIpAddress`
> - `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\NatNetwork`
>
> You can find and change your WSL instance IP in this registry key:
>
> `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`
>
> [image: reg1]
> [image: reg2]
>
> The WSL instance IP and host IP relative to WSL instance will not change even you restart your computer, if you leave these registry keys unmodified.
>
> If you want to change WSL IP, just edit these registry keys, then restart your computer, and new WSL IP setting will be applied when you open WSL.
> In another word, now it is really OK to set a static IP for WSL.
>
> My OS is Windows 11 Enterprise (Build 22621.1702), and WSL version is 1.2.5.0.
> Also, there is one thing to mention, that my VMware NAT/HostOnly Network and WSL instance are now able to access mutually through IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want /etc/hosts, /etc/resolv.conf to change after restart, you can create
/etc/wsl.conf

```
[network]
generateHosts = false
generateResolvConf = false
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a bat file and put it in autorun

   wsl sudo ip addr add 192.168.99.2/24 broadcast 192.168.99.255 dev eth0 label eth0:1;
   netsh interface ip add address "vEthernet (WSL (Hyper-V firewall))" 192.168.99.1 255.255.255.0
2. add entries with your sites to the hosts file
   192.168.99.2 you-site1.local
   192.168.99.2 you-site2.local
   ...
3. enjoy!